# Calling a web service from .net results in Catastrophic Failure

Tags: c#, .net

Occasionally when I try to instantiate a generated .net web service proxy class, it throws a catastrophic error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000FFFF): Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GetLocationEvidence(SafePEFileHandle peFile, SecurityZone& zone, StringHandleOnStack retUrl)
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateLocationEvidence()
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   at System.Security.Policy.AssemblyEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean markDelayEvaluatedEvidenceUsed)
   at System.Security.Policy.AppDomainEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.RawEvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.EvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetEvidenceInfo(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath, String& typeName)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetTypeAndHashSuffix(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.ConfigurationManagerInternal.System.Configuration.Internal.IConfigurationManagerInternal.get_ExeProductName()
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Initializer()
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.CreateSetting(PropertyInfo propInfo)
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Properties()
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertyValueByName(String propertyName)
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPropertyValue(String propertyName)
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at someService..ctor()
```

After this error occurs, any further attempts to instantiate the proxy again produces the following error:

```
System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyNotFoundException: The settings property 'localhost_someService' was not found.
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertyValueByName(String propertyName)
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPropertyValue(String propertyName)
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at someService..ctor()
```

It seems to be erroring out when it tries to retrieve a value from the settings file that gets generated when creating the proxy class
(i.e. Properties.Settings.Default.[key]).

Has anyone ever encountered this issue or know of a way to resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the web service added as a ServiceReference or a WebReference? Please all post the instantiate code

Comment: Its being added as a web reference. The constructor code is:                                                                public someService() {
            this.Url = global::namespace.Properties.Settings.Default.localhost_someService;
            if ((this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(this.Url) == true)) {
                this.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = false;
            }
            else {
                this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = true;
            }
        }